# C# Can't save Null in Database from DateTimePicker

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6, datetimepicker

I have a DateTimePicker in my Windows Form which I need to let it save NULL in database if user has not choose any date.

However, even if I do not choose any date (check is false), the value saved in the database is the current date.

So, my project is in EF6.

This is my Entity property:

```
[Display(Name = "Data Entrega")]
[Column(TypeName = "datetime2")]
public DateTime? DataEntregue { get; set; }
```

This is my Form with the DateTimePicker:

The Handler:

```
private void dataEntrega_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (((DateTimePicker)sender).ShowCheckBox == true)
    {
        if (((DateTimePicker)sender).Checked == false)
        {
            ((DateTimePicker)sender).CustomFormat = " ";
            ((DateTimePicker)sender).Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        }
        else
        {
            ((DateTimePicker)sender).CustomFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd";
            ((DateTimePicker)sender).Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ((DateTimePicker)sender).CustomFormat = " ";
        ((DateTimePicker)sender).Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
    }
}
```

The SaveChanges:

```
DbContext ctx = new DbContext();
Tools tl = new Tools()
{
    DataEntregue = dataEntrega.Value,
    Comentarios = txtComentarios.Text.Trim(),
    CreatedBy = Extensions.UserInfo.CurrentLoggedUser,
    CreatedOn = DateTime.Now
};
ctx.Tools.Add(tl);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

Can anyone help me figure out why I cannot get NULL into database?

Thanks

Comment: You should use `DBNull.Value` if a variable is null.

Comment: `DataEntregue = dataEntrega.HasValue ? dataEntrega.Value : DBNull.Value` might work?

Comment: @TJWolschon With EntityFramework you don't have to use `DBNull.Value`, you just use `null`.

Comment: If your `dataEntrega` is nullable `DateTime` and if you use `dataEntrega.Value` when `dataEntrega` is `null`, it will throw a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have assumed your DateTimePicker control is called `dataEntrega`

Even though you have changed the Display Format of the DateTimePicker to clear the displayed value, it still has an underlying DateTime value which you are accessing via the `Value` property.

In your `SaveChanges`, when assigning to the `DataEntregue` property you should check the `Checked` property of the DateTimePicker and act accordingly.

```
if(dataEntrega.Checked)
{
    DataEntrega = dataEntrega.Value;
}
else
{
    DataEntrega = null;
}
```

Comment: Yep, that worked. I had to check before the DbContext for every DateTimePicker for check or not and then, in DbContext pass those values to database! Thanks

Comment: Do you mean that you have lots of DateTimePickers in your UI code and have to repeat this step lots of times?

Comment: @CarlosFerreira make an extension method ValueChecked for the DateTimePicker where you do the check and return null.